# Does a free alternative to Proxifier or ProxyCap exist?

Tags: macos, applications, socks

Currently, I'm not at home so I must use the hotel's hotspot. Unfortunately, the majority of ports are closed, except 80, 443 and 22, and I would like to connect to my FTP, or connect Steam to play my games, etc.

I tested ProxyCap and Proxifier which redirected all my traffic to my sock server at home, but trials versions has expired, and I don't want to pay for something that I use a few weeks in a year.
I know I can set the proxies settings in my Mac settings, but all the applications don't use it (like Steam).

Does a free alternative of ProxyCap and Proxifier exist on MacOSX?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Spotflux](http://www.spotflux.com/) provides a managed and trusted connection to the internet that immediately reacts to and protects against emerging threats and unwanted tracking that affect mobile devices and desktop computers.

Another alternative exists in the form of extensions for Chrome & firefox:

- [Mediahint](https://mediahint.com/)
- [Hola Unblocker](http://hola.org/)

I have however only tried these extensions on the aforementioned web browsers on the Windows platform, and as yet have not tried them on OS X.

Comment: Thank you, it worked! Very easy to configure, and connects to my FTP or Steam! The ping is around 300 to reach google.com, not enough to play but enough to chat and connect to games.

Comment: @tib20 Welcome :)

Comment: This does not answer the question. Jedihy's answer below is correct. Also the link to spotflux, ends up on sophos website. Please update the correct answer @Tiwenty

Answer (score 7):

Try proximac.
https://github.com/csujedihy/proximac

Proximac is an command-line open-source alternative to Proxifier. With Proximac, it can force App to use SOCKS5 proxy. In the other words, it can forward any App's traffic to a specified SOCKS5 proxy. Moreover, Proximac now can forward all network traffic in your system to a proxy which means you may not need a VPN to do this job. I hope more developers can join this project.

Comment: Don't understand why my answer get a -1 vote...

Comment: Hey it's the only solution that worked the way I wanted, thank you for your effort!

Comment: here's your +1 to compensate unfair minus :)

Answer (score 3):

The alternative I use is [Hotspot Shield](http://www.hotspotshield.com)

If you are running Steam, remember to launch it with -tcp as follows:

```
open /Applications/Steam.app --args -tcp
```

Comment: Strange, I installed it, launched it, it said I was connected and launch your command. But Steam didn't connect. But I found, thanks to another answer, Spotflux that is really easy and totally free. But as I am curious, I'll continue to search why it doesn't work here. What options do you have?

Comment: Hotspot Shield sometimes doesn't work here too, and it only masks ports 80 and 443. I'm going to try Spotflux as well.

Answer (score 0):

Privoxy does a good job - can be customised or used in standard configuration. Customising means to dig "quite deep" into the description and to really know what your are supposing to do.